# Determine if field is an element of a set

Tags: python, rethinkdb-python

Using RethinkDB's `filter()` function, given a field called **field**, how do we determine if **field** is an element of a set `['value1', 'value2'...'valueN']`, and only filter rows where **field** is in such set?

One would *be very pleased to see* RethinkDB support Python's `in` operator, i.e.:

`table.filter(r.row['field'] in ["value1", "value2", "valueN"])`

But this is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Using short-hand Python, and RethinkDB's `or_` function, this can be accomplished with the following one-liner:

```
table.filter(r.or_(*tuple([r.row['field'] == val for val in values] )))
```